# Type error when testing a function with a negative number

Tags: haskell, literals, type-signature

I am following along with the *Learn you a Haskell for great good*, I have implemented `take'`:

```
take' :: (Ord i, Num i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take' n _
  | n <= 0 = []
take' _ [] = []
take' n (x:xs) = x: take' (n-1) xs
```

When testing the function with:

```
take' -2 [2]
```

instead of getting an empty list, I have this message:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (i -> [a] -> [a])
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall i a t.
            (Num i, Num t, Num (i -> [a] -> [a]), Num ([t] -> i -> [a] -> [a]),
             Ord i) =>
            i -> [a] -> [a]
```

I have added a space between `-` and `2` as suggested, and it leads to the same error:

```
*Main> take' - 2 [2]

<interactive>:78:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (i -> [a] -> [a])
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall i a t.
            (Num i, Num t, Num (i -> [a] -> [a]), Num ([t] -> i -> [a] -> [a]),
             Ord i) =>
            i -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Hint: put a space between `-` and `2`. Does that make the code behave differently?

Comment: @leftaroundabout tried adding a difference between - and 2, it behaves much the same

Comment: @leftaroundabout `(-2)` worked, I think it was attempting to apply `-` as a function instead of evaluating the number `-2`

Comment: Yep, I think that's what @leftaroundabout was pointing out (where the space makes it more clear to see it as an infix operator)

Comment: The issue here is that `take -2 [1,2]` means `(take) - (2 [1])` this uses `take` as a number and `2` as a function. IMO, the error message is not very informative to a beginner, and GHC should emit a better one for `Num (_ -> _)` unresolved constraints.

Comment: @chi: Could you put that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @TikhonJelvis I was about to that earlier, but I didn't want to "steal" the answer/comment of from leftaroundabout

Comment: @chi don't be sheepish. Like I cared! It's not as if you needed that hint to analyse the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, this is simply a matter of parsing rules. Your expression `take' -2 [2]` sure looks like it should mean `take' (-2) [2]` as you intend. And arguably, it should be parsed as just that. In fact GHC has an extension to achieve that behaviour:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XNegativeLiterals 
Prelude> take -2 [2]
[]
```

By default however, Haskell always first tries to parse all operators, including `-`, as *infix operators*. In the above expression, `-` has both something to the left and to the right (albeit with inconsistent spacing, but that's ignored), so without `-XNegativeLiterals` this ends up getting parsed as `(take) - (2 [2])`, which means something completely different. Really it's just utter bogus, as the error message suggests in a really cryptic way: it wants `Num (i -> [a] -> [a])`, i.e. it finds your code requires to treat a function (namely, `take`) as a number (namely, as an argument to the subtraction operator).

Almost always when you see an error including demand for `Num (Some Compound Type)` it means something is completely wrong already at the parsing level.